# HTTP Post Form Data With Fields That Already Have Values

Tags: android, forms, http-post, retrofit, okhttp

I am attempting to add a native login for a Jasig CAS to my Android app. I am using OkHttp (and/or RetroFit) to perform the HTTP post operation. The HTML login form looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="login" class="fm-v" action="/cas/login" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-{login ticket}">
    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="{execution value}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_event" value="submit">

    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" tabindex="1"
        placeholder="Username" class="textfield" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" tabindex="2"
        placeholder="Password" class="textfield" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" tabindex="3"
        class="button" value="Submit">

</form>
```

From what I understand the "POST" method when added to the URL looks something like this:

```
"url.base.com/extension?post_name=post_value&..."
```

So I have found that when I use either OkHttp or RetroFit, the post method uses a URL like this:

```
"login.example.com/cas/login?username={username}&password={password}"
```

When typed into any browser, this is redirected to the standard login page: `login.example.com/cas/login`. But what I have found, is that if I follow this format:

```
"login.example.com/cas/login?lt=LT-{current-login-ticket}
    &execution={current-execution-value}&_event=submit&username={username}
    &password={password}&submit=Submit"
```

I receive a successful login! But I have to use a current login ticket and execution value. Therefore, is there any way to automatically fill out the rest of the form data based on the values that are given? Or do I have to parse the HTML response myself to get the login ticket and execution value?